# external connections by unused gvfsd-smb?

Tags: security, samba

I have never used samba.  And yet, several times recently I noticed my machine ramp up to 100% CPU recently due to gvfsd-smb-browse; doing lsof on the process, I found it had external connections going.  Should I be alarmed?

Here's the relevant stuff:

```
$ top
[ ... ]
5787 peter     20   0  716324  16076  13496 S 100.0  0.1   9:04.81 gvfsd-smb-brows
$ lsof -p 5787
[ ... ]
gvfsd-smb 5787 peter  mem       REG                8,1   153520  398074 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsmbclient.so.0.2.3
gvfsd-smb 5787 peter  mem       REG                8,1   153288  669316 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
gvfsd-smb 5787 peter  mem       REG                8,1    26258  439449 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gconv/gconv-modules.cache
gvfsd-smb 5787 peter  DEL       REG                8,1           530954 /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/gschemas.compiled
gvfsd-smb 5787 peter  mem       REG                8,1   548960  655696 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsystemd.so.0.16.0
gvfsd-smb 5787 peter  mem       REG                8,1    76216  655567 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_myhostname.so.2
gvfsd-smb 5787 peter  DEL       REG                8,3          6305890 /home/peter/.config/dconf/user
gvfsd-smb 5787 peter  DEL       REG               0,38            85239 /run/user/1000/dconf/user
gvfsd-smb 5787 peter    0r      CHR                1,3      0t0    1028 /dev/null
gvfsd-smb 5787 peter    1u     unix 0xffff88003664d480      0t0   23679 type=STREAM
gvfsd-smb 5787 peter    2u     unix 0xffff880429425b40      0t0   23680 type=STREAM
gvfsd-smb 5787 peter    3u  a_inode               0,11        0    8279 [eventfd]
gvfsd-smb 5787 peter    4u     unix 0xffff88037e863440      0t0   84540 type=STREAM
gvfsd-smb 5787 peter    5u  a_inode               0,11        0    8279 [eventfd]
gvfsd-smb 5787 peter    6u  a_inode               0,11        0    8279 [eventfd]
gvfsd-smb 5787 peter    7u  a_inode               0,11        0    8279 [eventfd]
gvfsd-smb 5787 peter    8u  a_inode               0,11        0    8279 [eventpoll]
gvfsd-smb 5787 peter    9r      CHR                1,9      0t0    1033 /dev/urandom
gvfsd-smb 5787 peter   10u     IPv4              83847      0t0     TCP 192.168.1.53:50852->192.168.1.72:netbios-ssn (ESTABLISHED)
gvfsd-smb 5787 peter   11u     unix 0xffff88007651eb40      0t0   83453 @/dbus-vfs-daemon/socket-qFwAs1jA type=STREAM
gvfsd-smb 5787 peter   12u     IPv4            3098888      0t0     TCP skua.home:41460->unallocated.barefruit.co.uk:netbios-ssn (SYN_SENT)
```